# unknown ISRA exception while uploading a doc IN Filenet

Tags: java, filenet-p8, filenet-image-services

I have setup ISRA in my local webshpere and trying to upload a document to filenet thourgh ISRA. The ISRA connection  is happening fine but, I am getting the following exception while trying to upload document through ISRAutil.jar and ISRA.jar:

```
at com.citigroup.rel.citip8.pe.PEUtils.uploadDocument(PEUtils.java:434)
at com.citigroup.rel.citip8.pe.PEUtils.uploadDocumentNewImage(PEUtils.java:334)
at com.citigroup.rel.defaultmail.action.WorkItemDetailOpsAction.delete(WorkItemDetailOpsAction.java:418)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:276)
at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:196)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:421)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:226)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1164)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:415)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1147)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:722)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:449)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1020)

Caused by: 
com.citigroup.rel.adg.israutil.v1.ISRAUtilException: Error running AddDoc
at com.citigroup.rel.adg.israutil.v1.ISRAUtilDao.addDocument(ISRAUtilDao.java:271)
at com.citigroup.rel.adg.israutil.v1.ISUploadHelper.addDocument(ISUploadHelper.java:105)
at com.citigroup.rel.citip8.pe.PEUtils.uploadDocument(PEUtils.java:423)
... 36 more
Caused by: 
javax.resource.ResourceException: : Error in getting folder attributes.
at com.filenet.is.ra.cci.FN_IS_Document_Interactions.addDoc(Unknown Source)
at com.filenet.is.ra.cci.FN_IS_CciInteraction.executeInteractions(Unknown Source)
at com.filenet.is.ra.cci.FN_IS_CciInteraction.execute(Unknown Source)
at com.citigroup.rel.adg.israutil.v1.ISRAUtilDao.addDocument(ISRAUtilDao.java:266)




Can some1 please help me in this?
```